# (Delphi) How to use DosCommand Component?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have Installed https://github.com/TurboPack/DOSCommand on Rad Studio Berlin 10 update 2 but I cannot find out how to use it. I have tried playing around with it and I have searched through google looking for examples but I can't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your question does not have a detailed description. 
If you have the component installed successfully it should appear in the component palette. Please place it on your form, adjust properties in object inspector and call `Execute`.

BTW have you read "How to use it" and "Example" comments in the unit header?

```
 *******************************************************************
  How to use it :
  ---------------
  - just put the line of command in the property 'CommandLine'
  - execute the process with the method 'Execute'
```

Example

```
  Example : Make a dir :
  ----------------------
  - if you want to get the Result of a 'c:\dir /o:gen /l c:\windows\*.txt'
  for example, you need to make a batch file
  --the batch file : c:\mydir.bat
  @echo off
  dir /o:gen /l %1
  rem eof
  --in your code
  DosCommand.CommandLine := 'c:\mydir.bat c:\windows\*.txt';
  DosCommand.Execute;
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the late reply but for some reason I didn't have "How to use it" and "Example" comments in the unit header.

Comment: I'm really truly missing a documentation of the methods and properties of the component, while I can make hypothesis about their meaning and usage.
Can you point me to some documentation about the component parts ?
I have to execute silently a calculation engine that returns a list of strings containing astronomical data about celestial bodies (planets and so on).
I need to know how do do it silently, passing a command string with data to the program, and finally getting the results into a TMemo or something.